sqlplus connected against docker is slow to return control when calling exit
I have a docker container running Oracle.
When I connect to my database into my docker container:
$ sqlplus -L sys/password@"(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=ABP)))" as sysdba
and then I exit:
SQL> exit
the output is:
Disconnected from Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.19.0.0.0

and I have immediately control of the shell.
Now, I do exactly the same commands outside of docker. The connection is established quickly. However, when I type exit, the same output (Disconnected from Oracle...) is printed but it hangs for ~1 second before I get the control of the shell.
1 second is significant because I have to run a script that goes through hundreds/thousands of .sql files and calls sqlplus for each of them (sqlplus -L sys/password@"(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=ABP)))" as sysdba @"file1.sql") and it always takes at least one second to run while when I run the same command into my docker, it is immediate.
What could make sqlplus hang when exiting outside of my docker container?

hangs for ~1 second

Have you try to exec sqlplus with strace and compare the outputs?

I am on macOs and brew returns strace: Linux is required for this software.

@AntoineMartin, for MacOS you can use dtruss . Use this Q/A as starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31045575/2908599

the output for dtruss is
dtrace: failed to initialize dtrace: DTrace requires additional privileges```
I finally made my script copy the .sql files into my docker and run them from there.
thank you
